# Excel 2016 merging multiple tables with multiple product items

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have the following excel tables and wanted to merge them in a particular way (to eventually display all the items on a graph per day and include auto-trend lines).

[image]

With an output somthing like this (so it can then be line graphed per date for each ItemX on the same graph and auto-trend-lined)

[image]

I can't use macros to do this, so I was considering using the Data Model to create a Pivot Table, but I can't work out how to get the Quantities to match and start at the relevant dates per ItemX. I could also create the final table via formula's, but due to so many enties that would take too long to auto-create (5+ years worth)

**Update**:

See [attached](https://fastupload.io/C7ZIKBL14kkx/pTADmVG6N3Fmy6r/Zvqzl70Zn3aD2/test1.xlsx) example base-line file (this example is for Stock Exchange Codes and Portfolio Tracking).

I've been trying to get a history portfolio/stock tracker of value over time (stocks, inventory items, goods, products, etc.) by using a daily price and holding quantity for each item/Code. Using Excel 2016.

I was thinking perhaps when importing each file/data source when using PQ, to impiort each Code/Source and add them as Columns instead of at the end rows (since the dates will be the same) - perhaps adapting a version of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41271100/6400605, but modify to have the 1st column rows as the column headers of each source, then the 2nd colum is the common column for all sources.

Comment: your final output does not match your input.  Price per unit is different in the output that in your input. You need to explain the logic behind this and also post whay you've tried and where are you stuck.

Comment: Sorry, the output table price is the average of buy and sell price in Table2 ((buy+sell)/2). I'll update the post and try to outline my failed attempt(s) - I used a pivot table from the Data Model tables. The first issue is that I can't figure out if its even possible to match the Table1 Dates (purchase/sell dates) with the Table2 daily dates (when purchases/sales where made), to show the Balance Quantity per day using Table2 dates (onwards)

Comment: Looks like you need a unique id to match both datasets. Maybe a ID based on Product Code and Date could work for you? using an auxiliary column with values like `Item 1 01/04/2020, Item 1 02/04/2020...` and so on.

Comment: The issue with that approach is that multiple purchases can be made with the same code on the same date - I'm guessing could do unique ID with Code/Item+Date+Price (from the Trnsactions), but not sure how that will help with matching the Dates for daily prices. The Date matching is important (ie Daily Dates, and on the date of a purchase the Item QTY Balance/Balance QTY to be shown on those days onwards). Using complex formulas in the sheet lags calculations considerably, so I was thinking of doing it via a Pivot or maybe even in PQ on data import (or at least store each Items/Code by Columns)